# Get name of enclosing class indirectly

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

The purpose is to build a "TAG" value, which helps in logging & debugging. Basically when we perform logging we are interested in the name of the top-level enclosing class, not in used classes nor inner ones to understand the context of an action.

Here is my snippet, which works well with anonymous & inner, but fails on functions with receiver:

class B

```
class A {

    fun test() {
        B().apply {
            //get "A" string here
            println("$TAG: log message")
        }
    }
}

val Any.TAG: String
    get() = getTopLevelClass(this.javaClass).simpleName

private fun getTopLevelClass(clazz: Class<*>): Class<*> =
    clazz.enclosingClass?.let { getTopLevelClass(it) } ?: clazz
```

It outputs B, which doesn't give me much information about context where it is used

- I know, it can be achieved with `this@A.TAG`, but the thing you
  always should to remember and consider it on writing code, which i
  want to avoid.
- I know, it can be done with obtaining stacktrace, but
  is is very slow and not really trustable source. Logging should be
  ASAP and not affects an app speed.
- Environment is JVM 7, unfortunately i can't use `StackWalker`

So i think this is somehow possible with reflection, java one is preferable to not depend on kotlin-reflection package.

Comment: Maybe this example is just simplified, but maybe you should write some more information, than just `B` or `A` to the output. Maybe write: `Encountered someObject in A.test() while doing xyz`. You can then check your logs and search over your whole project for that message

Comment: yep, it is just simplification to point the problem, but i'll modify question to make it clear

Comment: If you can require Java 9, `StackWalker` should be much faster than the full stack trace.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately the environment is jvm 7

Comment: dumb and dirty idea, but you could generate an `interface` which holds a default method like this: `@JvmDefault fun printTAG() = println(TAG)`. It only works though when `A`  implements it, but `B` doesn't